# What is better to say in the following context "You 'could' / 'would' achieve"?

Tags: modal-verbs

How is it better to say

> Sometimes it's hard to believe that you **could** ever achieve your
>   goal...

Or

> Sometimes it's hard to believe that you **would** ever achieve your
>   goal...

Comment: There are a lot of questions related to *could versus would*. Please search.

Comment: In this context, could refers to the ability to accomplish the goal, would is referring to the intention to accomplish the goal. Consider the difference between "I can run" and "I will run". Since there's no reason to think a person lacks the intention to reach the goal, the issue is probably with the ability.